# Close socket opened by zsocket in zsh

Tags: zsh, unix-socket

I've done:

```
% zmodload zsh/net/socket
% zsocket -d 20 MY_SOCKET
# used the socket a bit
```

Now how do I close the socket's FD? (FD 20 here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00785.html) a mailing list post about `zsocket`:

> As far as I can see there's no way of closing the file descriptors using
>   zsocket, which seems an omission.  Presumably you can use "exec 3>&-"
>   etc. although to close a file descriptor over 9 you need to do something
>   like:

```
      % fd=11
      % exec {fd}>&-
```

I don't know exactly what `exec &-` does, but you could try:

```
fd=20
exec {fd}>&-
```